# fsck.ext4: How to force to check the whole file system?

Tags: ext4, fsck

It seems fsck.ext4 quit very soon, I guess it only checks the journal logs, and do nothing if the journal is clean. Is it? How to force it to check the whole file system? I've tried the `-f` option, but it quits again said it's clean very quickly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try:   `fsck -pvcf` -- will force a verbose check for bad blocks and automatically repair.  If you still have issues then your HDD might have physical problems.

Comment: Make sure that the filesystem is NOT mounted before performing a fsck command.

Answer (score 2):

On my machine, `e2fsck -fv <ext4-device>` takes a long while, about two to four minutes (the device is about 360 GiB full). So I assume it does a full check! I usually use `e2fsck -vfp -C0 <ext4-device>`, "`-p`" makes automatic fixing, "`-C0`" prints progress to stdout, and "`-v`" is for "verbose".

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution

```
sudo touch /forcefsck
```

fsck for ext3/ext4/... will be forced after reboot.